# Is there a way to protect url based on firebase roles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to restrict urls based on the role of the user singed in, I have the following HOC to do that

```
const withAuthorization = (authCondition) => (Component) => {
class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
    if (!authCondition(authUser)) {
      this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      {authUser => authUser ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  );
  }
}

return withRouter(WithAuthorization);
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

with the following code that restrict the url if the user is singed it works

```
const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser
export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Account);
```

and I can get the user role like this because I had to do at navigation to render different navBar based on roles

```
   authUser.getIdTokenResult(true) 
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
      if (!!idTokenResult.claims.student) //here I check if it is a student
```

the problem is how I mix now those things to pass the userRole to the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my HOC to receive another attribute now and changed the way it works with this code

```
const withAuthorization = (authCondition, neededRole) => (Component) => {
class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (!authCondition(authUser)) {
        this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
      }
      else if(neededRole=="ADMIN") {
        authUser.getIdTokenResult(true) 
        .then((idTokenResult) => {
            if(!idTokenResult.claims.admin){
               this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
              }
            })
          }
        else if(neededRole=="TEACHER") {
          authUser.getIdTokenResult(true) 
          .then((idTokenResult) => {
              if(!idTokenResult.claims.teacher && !idTokenResult.claims.admin){ //No teacher or admin
                 this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
                }
              })
            }
    });
  }

render() {
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      {authUser => authUser ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

return withRouter(WithAuthorization);
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

now my HOC first checks if the primary condition returns true, if yes it checks if I'm asking that component to be protected by role Admin or Teacher and I check it

with this code it works